# PIP cannot install Django inside VIrtualenv

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv

```
(myenv) wanjila@wanjila:~/Desktop/Python-Area/projects/Djangular$ pip freeze
djangorestframework==3.7.3
pkg-resources==0.0.0
(myenv) wanjila@wanjila:~/Desktop/Python-Area/projects/Djangular$ pip install django
Collecting django
  Using cached Django-2.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-qAnv7G/django/setup.py", line 32, in <module>
        version = __import__('django').get_version()
      File "django/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from django.utils.version import get_version
      File "django/utils/version.py", line 61, in <module>
        @functools.lru_cache()
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lru_cache'

------------------------------------
```

I keep getting that error whenever i try to pip install django while inside my virtualenv. How can i fix this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As an alternative to wim's answer, if you can't upgrade your Python version for whatever reason, you can install Django 1.11 which is still compatible with Python 2.7:

```
pip install 'django<2.0'
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your Python version in the virtualenv is Python 3.4+.

Django 2.0 only supports Python 3.4+, and [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) is only available in 3.2+.

To check the Python version in your current virtualenv:

```
python --version
```

To create a new virtualenv with python 3:

```
python3 -m venv venv --prompt=myenv
```

Comment: `venv: error: unrecognized arguments: --prompt=myenv` but this work
`python3 -m venv venv `

Answer (score 0):

This error is because of wrong picking of pip and python version . You can solve it by adding below lines in the ~/.bash_profile

```
  alias python='python3'
  alias pip='pip3.6'
```

After that close the terminal and run the following command to install Django

```
  pip install Django==2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

For latest version of Django, python 3 is required, thus try installing

```
pip install django==1.11
```